# “Soul Food” as describing non-African-American Food

Tags: vocabulary, metaphors

What is meant by “soul food” in the following text from the NYT?

> [For the uninitiated, kimchi is a tangy, pungent preserved vegetable preparation, like sauerkraut. To describe it only as a fermented vegetable mixture or a pickle, though, is hardly fair. This is Korean soul food.](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/01/21/dining/cooking-with-kimchi.html)

I thought “soul food” referred to [a type African-American cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_food). Is the NYT article making some parallel to African-American food? Or can “soul food” have some other more universal meaning, although not described in the Wikipedia entry? Also, [I have seen some Japanese food described this way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1607743523), but I have never heard European or Middle-Eastern cuisine described this way. I ask this because I myself eat ramen, tonkatsu, and tempura (the food described in the book above), but it would never occur to me to call these soul food; likewise, I eat kimchi just about every day, but I would never think of calling this soul food either. So what's the deal?

Comment: Contrast to *condiment*-- something ill-considered and sidelined-- to something fetishized and much beloved.  Turning something ordinary, like baked beans, into something extraordinary.  That's my take.  If you can make people rave about your fermented cabbage or your okra, maybe it's soul food.

Comment: Kimchi is Seoul food.

Answer (score 3):

> This is Korean soul food.

is using the term 'soul food' metaphorically.

It's primary meaning is very figurative already in the US. It means 'a selection of food prepared by African Americans in the north', food that is modest in source (i.e. cheap to grow or buy) but is full of taste (i.e. makes you feel good after eating, but will also give you a heart attack). The use of 'soul' was to imply that this is traditional, homey, heartwarming (literally!) food, good for your soul.

The selection of food is things like fried chicken, ribs, collard greens, corn bread, catfish, collard greens cooked with salt pork/fatback, pig maw, BBQ, all characterized by being very fatty or cooked with lard.

In the South, this kind of food, instead of being called 'soul food', is usually referred to as 'food'.

The selection of food is commonly prepared by whites in the South, but probably got its name during the Northern migration by contrast with the food of whites in the northern cities.

A more recent synonym for 'soul food' is ['comfort food'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comfort%20food). This refers to any food that makes you feel good. I suspect that the term 'comfort food' was coined in the late 80's in order to be like 'soul food' for white people, like mac and cheese, grilled cheese, and mayonnaise.

[image: soul vs comfort]

One might use 'soul food' for other cultures. Kimchi might be called Korean soul food because it might be soul food for Koreans, food that signifies traditional home meals, cheap modest food that makes you feel good.

It's definitely *not* the case that kimchi is part of African-American soul food; kimchi does not sit beside collard greens on the kitchen counter. 'Soul food' unqualified refers to the soul food of the US by default.

So "This is Korean soul food" just means that the Korean food made by this restaurant is being likened to the feeling you're supposed to get from the originally labeled African American soul food, but entirely in the context of Korean culture.

Answer (score 0):

According to multiple dictionaries, Soul Food can be described as:

> Traditional black American cookery, which originated in the rural
>   South, consisting of such foods as chitterlings, pig knuckles, turnip
>   greens, and cornbread.

But after searching on the web for a few minutes I came across a website showing an interview on [The true meaning of Soul Food](http://www.nola.com/dining/index.ssf/2014/07/the_meaning_of_soul_food_an_in.html).

In the interview, Adrian Miller said:

> soul food has more intense flavors. It's going to have more spice. It's going to be sweeter. It's a matter of intensity..)

After tasting Kimchi a few days ago, yes, it has quite an intense flavour. I suppose the NYT meant of what Adrian Miller had said.